# Find $A$ and $b$ such that $\|Ax_i + b\| \approx 1$ for a set of points $x_i, ..., x_N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm looking for some references on how to solve the following type of optimization problem:

Given data points $x_i, ..., x_N$ in $R^n$, find $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and vector $b$ such that $\|Ax_i + b\| \approx 1$ for all $x_i$.

I found an article solving this using the iterative closest point algorithm. I was wondering if there's another way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be formulated and solved as a linear least squares problem. A twist vs. the usual linear least squares problems is that $A$ is a matrix of unknowns (optimization variables) and $x$ is input data, whereas the roles of matrix and vector are reversed in the usual linear least squares problems.

To formulate, "vec" the matrix $A$ into a single vector, and re-write the problem. In the interests of simplicity and to reduce error propensity, it is easiest to use an optimization modeling tool which does this for you.  Here is how to formulate the problem in CVX (under MATLAB)). Similar tools exist for Python, R, and Julia.

Let X be the n by n matrix whose ith column is $x_i$.

```
cvx_begin
variable A(n,n)
minimize(norm(A*X + b*ones(n)-ones(n),'fro')
cvx_end
```

Comment: I don't think this code `minimize(norm(A*X + b*ones(n)-ones(n),'fro')` quite works.  $\|AX-1\|_F^2$ doesn't look equivalent to $\sum_i \| \|Ax_i\|^2_2 -1 \|^2_2$  Your version tries to make the components of the vectors $A x_i$ equal to one in magnitude, but OP want that $Ax_i$ is a unit vector

Comment: @Hyperplane norm is a scalar..It depends what the OP really wants.